Stuttering messenger in medieval times
I can't remember what film this is from but there is a comedy film that parodies the medieval era. There is a scene where two people are trying to do something so they ride to the kingdom but are stopped on the way by a band of royal knights who are headed somewhere. The two people stop them saying they bear a message. But the one who knows the message cant speak English so the other one interprets. The joke is that while they are trying to stall, the messenger is whispering into the interpreter's ear for like a minute then the interpreter responds "No". The knight asks why did it take so long to interpret, then the interpreter says he stutters. 

Sounds like The Court Jester with Danny Kaye from 1955:

Set in medieval England, the plot concerns the struggle to restore to the throne the rightful heir, a baby with a distinguishing birthmark, the purple pimpernel on his posterior. Danny Kaye plays Hubert Hawkins, an ex-carnival entertainer who becomes minstrel to the Black Fox, a Robin Hood-type character, (Edward Ashley), leader of the rebels in the forest who support the true infant-king.
The Black Fox orders Hawkins to carry the infant-king across the country to safety, accompanied by his comrade the maid Jean. On the journey, a romance blossoms between Hawkins and Jean.

There's a scene where royal knights stop Hawkins and Jean's carriage; Jean pretends to be a mute who only Hawkins can translate. They stall the knights for a bit and, after she signs a long sentence:

Hawkins: She says no.
Captain: What took her so long?
Hawkins: Stutters.

You can see the scene here around 4:35:



